# CSS based on text value of link

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some html (auto generated) like this :

```
<a>Save</a> &nbsp; <a>Cancel</a> &nbsp;
```

These two buttons are auto-generated via a framework so I have little control over the space between these two links. I want to include some more space in between the two buttons.
I have added some css

```
.fw-link {
margin-left: 6px!important;
margin-right: 6px!important;
}
```

but again this adds margin to the right of Cancel and Left of Save link - wasting much space.
Is it possible to write some CSS that applies based on the text value of LINK?

Comment: you're missing the & from &nbsp; use  either  2nd child selector a:nth-child(2) or a+a in your css. adding margin to the left one will pull the right one over I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS can be:

```
a {
   margin-left: 6px!important;
   margin-right: 6px!important;
}
a:first-child {
   margin-left: 0 !important;
} 
a:last-child {
   margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

What this will do is:
1. Add space between all links
2. Remove left margin from first link
3. Remove right margin from last link

[Sample codepen link](http://codepen.io/sunitJindal/pen/OPxOGW)

Answer (score 0):

use something like:

```
a:nth-child(1) { //1st a
    margin-right: 6px //!important needed?
}

a:nth-child(2) { //2nd a
    margin-left: 6px //!important needed?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attribute name.

```
<a name="save">Save</a> nbsp; <a name="cancel">Cancel</a> nbsp;
```

Then in your CSS file:

```
a[name=save] {
margin-right: 6px!important;
}
a[name=cancel] {
margin-left: 6px!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clover, but as I mentioned above I have no-control over dynamically generated Html. nada's answer worked.